# regex to match line that starts with one word but doesn't contain another word

Tags: regex

I am trying to define a regex to match lines that start with `aaa` but doesn't contain `xxx`. i. e. to match these lines:

> aaa bbb yyy
>
> aaa ooo zzz
>
> aaa bbgdb ooo

but not this:

> aaa ppp **xxx**

I tried to do this with:

```
aaa.*?(?!xxx)
```

but it matches all the mentioned lines.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `aaa.*?(?!xxx)` pattern matches `aaa` inside  a string, then checks if there is `xxx` immediately to the right of the current location (`.*?` is not even tried as it is a lazily quantified subpattern). Since there is a space after `aaa` in `aaa ppp xxx`, a valid match is returned.

You must add a `^` anchor at the start (also, you most probably need the `m` modifier, or the inline version of it, `(?m)`, at the start of the pattern) and put the `.*` or `.*?` inside the lookahead:

```
^aaa(?!.*?xxx).*
      ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IwEa0U/2/). Note you need to make `^` match start of a line with the appriopriate modifier, `m` (if not used in Ruby or tools like Notepad++ where `^` matches start of a line by default).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `aaa` - `aaa` substring
- `(?!.*?xxx)` - a negative lookahead that will fail the match if there is `xxx` substring after any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `.*` - the rest of the line, 0+ chars other than line break chars.

[image]